# Change filter on convolutional layer CNN - Python/TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, convolution

I have the following code block:

```
def new_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))
```

And:

```
def new_conv_layer(input,              # The previous layer
                   use_pooling=True):  # Use 2x2 max-pooling

    shape = [3, 3, 1, 8]

    weights = new_weights(shape=shape)

    biases = new_biases(length=8)

    layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input,
                         filter=weights,
                         strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                         padding='SAME')

    layer += biases

    if use_pooling:
        layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME')

    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

    # relu(max_pool(x)) == max_pool(relu(x)) we can
    # save 75% of the relu-operations by max-pooling first.

    return layer
```

So we can observe that the size of the filter is 3x3 and the number of filters is 8. And the filters are defined with random values.

What I need to do is to define all my 8 filters with fixed values, ie predetermined values, for example:

```
weigths = [
    [[0,  1, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 1,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 1,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 1,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  1, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[1,  0, 0,],], 
    [[0,  0, 0,],[1, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[1,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],]
]
```

I can not imagine, how could I do inside my code, this modification, does anyone have any idea how I could do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want initialize weight by some predefined value you can use `tf.constant_initializer`. If you don't want train this weights, you can define them as `tf.constant` not `tf.Variable`

```
def new_weights(init_vaue, is_const):
    if (is_const) :
        return tf.constant(init_vaue, name='weights')
    else:
        initializer = tf.constant_initializer(init_vaue)
        return tf.get_variable('weights', shape = init_vaue.shape, initializer=initializer)

weights = np.ones([3,3,1,8], dtype=np.float)
print(weights.shape)

value = new_weights(weights, True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    value_ = sess.run(value) 
    print(value_)
```

Comment: Ups, sorry. Fix it.

Comment: But where do I set my 8 filters? Inside new_weights ()?

Comment: you should change line `weights = np.ones([3,3,1,8], dtype=np.float)` to some code, which fills `weights` array.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it in TF2:

```py
model = models.Sequential()
# one 3x3 filter
model.add(layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), input_shape=(None, None, 1)))
# access to the target layer
layer = model.layers[0]
current_w, current_bias = layer.get_weights()  # see the current weights
new_w = tf.constant([[1,2, 3],
                     [4, 5, 6],
                     [7, 8, 9]])
new_w = tf.reshape(new_w, custom_w.shape)  # fix the shape
new_bias = tf.constant([0])
layer.set_weights([new_w, new_bias])
model.summary()
# let's see ..
tf.print(model.layers[0].get_weights())
```

Answer (score 1):

You just define the weights as non-trainable and define the new weights as:

```
new_weights = tf.Variable( tf.reshape(weights, (3,3,1,8)),trainable=False)
# then apply on the inputs 
layer = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, filter=new_weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: I do not understand, can you explain more?

Comment: I did this and get the following error:

**TypeError: Input 'filter' of 'Conv2D' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'input'.**

Comment: Cast your weights to float32, tf.Variable( tf.reshape(tf.cast(weights, tf.float32), (3,3,1,8)), trainable=False),

Comment: That way you did, you no longer use **def new_weights(shape):**? I honestly do not know if I set up the structure correctly...